# How to prevent losing .gitignore when checking-out older branches?

Tags: git

If I am in master and stuff I want safe from git is ignored, I then:

```
    git checkout <oldbranch or commit>
```

But the old branch doesn't have the ignored files arrgh!  So now the untracked files could get added etc and are vulnerable to reset --hard etc.

Is there more elegant fix here other than:

```
    git checkout master .gitignore
    #maybe write a hook to do this every checkout of <oldbranch or commit>?
```

Or  constantly manage copying .gitignore into `.git/info/exclude`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding rules in `.git/info/exclude` is one way, but it remains a *local* workaround: it won't get pushed like a `.gitignore` file would.

The best option remains to create the `.gitignore` in the checked out branch:

```
git checkout aBranchWithoutGitignore
git checkout master -- .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Add .gitignore from master"
```

Then [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) that commit to other branches.

Comment: Ok so my first example hmm...  would it be safe to make a hook  that does this?  I spose I could just make a git alias.  This is really dodgy for new people who have a lot of stuff in there ignore the could easy destroy work that was sposed to be ignored.

Comment: @sabgenton no hook necessary: once the `.gitignore` is created in one branch, and cherry-picked in others, all that is left to do is to push all those branches and make sur the other devs are pulling them in their own local repo; then the .gitignore will be everywhere, and any new branch done from the current branch will include it. It is a one-time operation, plus some communication.

Comment: I guess it covers most cases, I was just thinking say you checkout -b foo HEAD~~~   then the problem will come back.  So you have to be on your toes.

Comment: No, it wouldn't come back, because the `HEAD` you branch from will have the .gitignore file and then so will the new branch. .gitignore is just like any other file under Git's control (except for that Git uses the information in it, whereas Git doesn't 'use' the contents of source code files, etc.)

Comment: Huh?  If just the HEAD commit has .gitignore (because I put it there like in VonCs example)  why would it suddenly appear in the commit 3 commits down from HEAD?

Comment: @MicroVirus I agree with the reset of what your saying however.

Comment: @sabgenton because putting it in a HEAD commit serves to create a commit with just the `.gitignore` in it. You can then cherry-pick that single commit to the other branches lacking the `.gitignore`, and then push every modified branches, for others to benefit from the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Yes I agree I'm just saying if you do branch from HEAD~<n>  then you have to apply another cherry pick.  I wish you never had to think about it again is all I'm getting at.  I wish there was a better way but I'm guessing this is it. :)

Comment: @VonC  ahhh! I just found out your ignored files get clobbered if you checkout a commit that had a different version of the files, heard of this happening?  I have never seen this on SO.  (note was a test repo :)  )

Comment: @sabgenton the .gitignore are added from a certain point in the history of a repo. If you select a SHA1 which precede that point, the .gitignore would not be visible.

Comment: I have given your answer the tick and +1 for the cherry pick comment :D

Comment: @sabgenton sorry, I cannot access your link at work, I will see it at home in a few hours.

Comment: No prob thanks very much for your time! :D,
http://sprunge.us/OFBg for pasting http://sprunge.us/OFBg?bash for reading :P

Comment: @sabgenton arf... still blocked by our firewall ;)

Comment: @VonC I chucked it in to my question body temporarily

Comment: @sabgenton I see. I would recommend using `git stash` *before* any git checkout  of an older SHA1. (and `git stash pop` after the checkout)

Comment: @VonC I thought git stash didn't work on ignored and untracked?

Comment: `git stash
No local changes to save`

Comment: @sabgenton sorry, I forgot the option `--all` (`git stash --all`): http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Comment: @VonC ah good to know, still I don't see this as practical, wont that take forever with large files (like with git add)?

Comment: @sabgenton I agree, this is more a workaround. This case would be a good question of its own, to see of other Git experts have a different advice.

Comment: @VonC Yes :) curious were you aware of this issue?
Its the first time git has silently deleted stuff I added when checking out another commit!

Comment: I will stop at that and possibly make another question. Thanks again!

Comment: @VonC new question asked (but same result) :)